Send a welcome message to Microsoft Teams chat before the user sends a message
I am using azure bot service to implement the bot, without using SDK from them. So please do not write about the need to use SDK.
The Microsoft requirement is to provide a welcome message before the user writes the message. But as much as I have tested, ConversationUpdate, which in theory should appear immediately after the user joins the chat, but it appears only after the user has written a message.


Before a user sends me a message I don't know anything about them.
I also see that people who use non webhoocks from azure bot also get the same problem.
Please don't answer with theoretical data from documentation, they are very often not true, also don't use llm. I couldn't find actual solutions for this problem, it is desirable that the answer should be based on real tests.

You've tagged this as a Teams question, so presumably you're using/wanting to use this bot in Teams - are you doing that already? It's important because I think the sequence of events you're wanting is different based on that

@HiltonGiesenow Yeah, I have many bots for this, but they are not all published in the global market, and now there is one that needs to be published. For more correct tests, I uninstalled the app from tams and then reinstalled it, and created new apps, the result was the same, ms-teams creates a draft in the chat (which does not send the ConversationUpdate event), and only after the user writes there, this event is sent with the first message.

Are you deploying an actual Teams app for your bot? Or just connecting to it directly in Teams?

@HiltonGiesenow 2. I have a server that communicates with azure bot, then through dev.teams.microsoft.com/apps I connect this bot and create an archive for publishing that can be used by any user from tams. So yes, I don't use a separate teams for this purpose, this is aimed at a large number of different users.

No, I was referring to something else. Do you have the bot deployed as an actual "App" in Teams - can people go and install it from the "internal app" collection? To do this, you would have had to create an app manifest and upload it into the internal app store using one of the means of doing that.

@HiltonGiesenow In that case, yes, it is deployed. People download the archive with the manifest and install it. And we also gave this archive for certification.

ok, that's good - that can easily be a cause for this. If they're installing the bot via the App store though, then it should be firing the event properly - I'm not sure why that's not occurring

@HiltonGiesenow They often have different jokes that are not logical, for example also a problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78516949/azure-bot-service-get-video-clip

I understand that your requirement is to send a Welcome message in the Teams channel even before user types his first input message.
To achieve this requirement, you can make use of the Proactive messages .
This message is used for sending Welcome message, Notification and Scheduled message.
The steps to send proactive message and the sample codes are all shared here.
Hope this helps.

Proactive messages are NOT for sending Welcome messages

NaveenBalig I told you to answer only with actual verified facts (I didn't give you v).
@HiltonGiesenow Proactive messages can poison the first messages, but we have to understand to whom we send them. Since this is not an application (in which the indication process is a bit different from azure bot service), but a bot that immediately opens a chat (which is draft until the user writes), there is no such possibility. The funny thing is that I don't want to send this message either, but the company's requirements are trying to require something for which they haven't provided the tools

@HiltonGiesenow By an application I meant an app with many features included, not just bot features.
